# A countable space embedding question

Tags: general-topology

For any countable space $X$, can it be embedded into $\{0,1\}^c$  ($c=2^\omega$)?

Thanks advance.

Comment: Are you specifying a topology?  If not, what if $X$ has the trivial topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every subspace of $\{0,1\}^{\mathfrak c}$ is Tikhonov, and there are certainly countable spaces that are not Tikhonov, so the answer is *no*. Every countable $T_3$-space, however, is zero-dimensional and therefore can be embedded in $\{0,1\}^{\mathfrak c}$, since $\{0,1\}^{\mathfrak c}$ is universal for zero-dimensional spaces of weight at most $\mathfrak c$, and the weight of a countable space clearly cannot exceed $\mathfrak c$.